# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token"

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
int sizex = 3;
int sizey = 3;
int * grid;
grid = new int [sizex][sizey];  // Line 6
grid = {{0}};
```

I am trying to declare an array here but the compiler says

> Line 6: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token

Can you help me figure out why?

Comment: @Oli Not reading line 3 apparently ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because the syntax is wrong. That's not how you allocate memory.

If you want a matrix, you probably want

```
int** grid;
```

and you allocate memory like this:

```
grid = new int*[sizex];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizex ; i++ )
   grid[i] = new int[sizey];
```

Also, the assignment `grid = {{0}};` doesn't really make sense after you've already allocated memory for `grid`.

Don't forget to delete the memory.

Comment: @user1277552 it does work, but you didn't put it in context. Put it inside `main` or some other function.

Comment: @user1277552 there - http://codepad.org/3Gi4vIEB - and I also said the assignment `grid={{0}}` doesn't make sense after the allocation.

Comment: there is still some kind of error that I just cant figure out? DO you haave any idea? http://codepad.org/nruKlIAv

Comment: @user1277552 post a new question with the updated code and the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @user1277552 also, for the **third** time, the assignment `grid={{0}}` is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated by Luchian and Mark B, the use of `new` to create the 2D array is incorrect.

If you want to initialise all of the elements use the following construct:

```
grid = new int*[sizex];
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizex ; i++)
   grid[i] = new int[sizey]();
                         //^^
```

this will initialise the elements to zero.

You can't use:

```
grid = {{0}};
```

for assignment: `{}` can only be used at initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that syntax to directly create 2d arrays in C++. While you can use the somewhat obscure syntax noted in a comment (`int (*p)[6] = new int[3][6];`) I don't suggest doing that as it will probably just overly complicate your code.

Instead what you want is a vector of vectors. Using vector effectively foolproofs your memory management since C++ isn't garbage collected.

`std::vector<std::vector<int> > grid(sizex, std::vector<int>(sizey));`

Comment: Pedantry alert: Your first sentence isn't entirely accurate.  Stuff like this is valid: `int (*p)[6] = new int[3][6];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int main(){
      int** grid;
      int sizex = 5;
      int sizey = 5;
      grid = new int*[sizex];
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizex ; i++ )
         grid[i] = new int[sizey];

// ... a lot of code 

// .. deleting:
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizex ; i++ )
             delete [] grid[i];
       delete [] grid; 
    }
```

Comment: How is this any different than the answer I posted 20 minutes ago?

Comment: It's compiles, i just was surprised  whats wrong with yours and place everything here, is it wrong?